# retrofit - how to get response from json object

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit, retrofit2

i need to get json object in the link

```
http://link/json
```

and my json review

```
{"as":"AS48159 Telecommunication Infrastructure Company","city":"Ahvāz","country":"Iran","countryCode":"IR","isp":"Information Technology Company (ITC)","lat":31.3167,"lon":48.6844,"org":"khouzestan Telecommunication co","query":"2.185.10.22","region":"","regionName":"Khuzestan","status":"success","timezone":"Asia/Tehran","zip":""}
```

but i get error in activitymain.java

```html
Incompatible types.
Required:
retrofit2.Call
<ir.hmotamed.myipnet.Queryip>
Found:
ir.hmotamed.myipnet.Queryip
```

my seryalize ( Queryip.java )

```js
public class Queryip {

    @SerializedName("status")
    private String status;
    @SerializedName("query")
    private String query;
    @SerializedName("country")
    private String country;
    @SerializedName("countryCode")
    private String countryCode;
    @SerializedName("city")
    private String city;
    @SerializedName("timezone")
    private String timezone;
    @SerializedName("isp")
    private String isp;
```

my interface ( ApiService.java )

```js
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;

public interface ApiService {

    @GET("json")
    Call<Queryip> getQueryip();
}
```

and mu activitymain.java its

```js
public class ActivityMain extends AppCompatActivity {

    Call<Queryip> queryip;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ApiService service=ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiService.class);
        Call<Queryip> call=service.getQueryip();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<Queryip>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Queryip> Call, Response<Queryip> response) {

                queryip=response.body(); // this line show error

                Toast.makeText(ActivityMain.this, "ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Queryip> Call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(ActivityMain.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

i need help for fix error and get object for show text view
tanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`response.body();` can be casted to your POJO class i.e. `Queryip`

You are assigning it to reference **Call** class. That's the issue here

Try :

`Queryip q = (Queryip)response.body()`

Comment: tanks for your help ! // but after fix in code `queryip=response.body();

                txt_ip_activitymain.setText(queryip.getStatus());
                Toast.makeText(ActivityMain.this, "ok " + queryip.getStatus(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` get metod in toast its ok but in set text get error!

Comment: Please elaborate the issue. And if possible, also post the error prone code

Comment: two image for error its : [image 1 show error in logcat](https://up.20script.ir/file/96f2-2018-11-05-11-59-15.png) and [imae 2 show by debug](https://up.20script.ir/file/96f2-2018-11-05-12-05-43.png)

Comment: Looking at the "debug" image that you shared, the text view is null. Make sure you have initialised it using findViewById(R.id.<id_of_text_view>) before this line gets executed

Comment: ohw yes tanks! im forget to set findviewbyid but after set my coe go to onFailure

Comment: happy to help...!

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you create Call object

Just create object as below

```
Queryip queryip
```

and in onSuccess

```
queryip=response.body();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's where your snippet is wrong.

Your global declared variable `queryip` is of type `Call<Queryip>`:

```
Call<Queryip> queryip;
```

Now, in api response you are trying to assign `queryip` with `response.body()` which is why you are getting error.

`response.body()` will return object of type `Queryip` but your variable is of type `Call<Queryip>`.

So, simply refactor your variable declaration from:

```
Call<Queryip> queryip;
```

to

```
Queryip queryip;
```

Thats it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you need to change your global object type from Call to Queryip in your activitymain.java
then in onResponse:
you can access queryip=response.body();